# Repeatedly apply a conditional summary to groups in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a large dataframe that looks like this:

```
group_id    distance    metric
       1         1.1      0.85
       1         1.1      0.37
       1         1.7      0.93   
       1         2.3      0.45 
       ...
       1         6.3      0.29
       1         7.9      0.12
       2         2.5      0.78
       2         2.8      0.32
       ...
```

The dataframe is already sorted by `group_id` and then `distance`. I want know the dplyr or data.table efficient equivalent to doing the following operations:

Within each `group_id`:

1. Let the unique and sorted values of `distance` within the current  `group_id` be `d1,d2,...,d_n`.
2. For each `d` in `d1,d2,...,d_n`: Compute some function `f` on all values of `metric` whose `distance` value is less than `d`. The function `f` is a custom user defined function, that takes in a vector and returns a scalar. Assume that the function `f` is well defined on an empty vector.

So, in the example above, the desired dataframe would look like:

```
group_id    distance_less_than    metric
       1                   1.1      f(empty vector)
       1                   1.7      f(0.85, 0.37)
       1                   2.3      f(0.85, 0.37, 0.93) 
       ...
       1                   7.9      f(0.85, 0.37, 0.93, 0.45,...,0.29)
       2                   2.5      f(empty vector)
       2                   2.8      f(0.78)
       ...
```

Notice how `distance` values can be repeated, like the value `1.1` under group `1`. In such cases, both of the rows should be excluded when the distance is less than `1.1` (in this case this results in an empty vector).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible approach is to use non-equi join available in `data.table`. The left table is the unique set of combinations of group_id and distance and right table are all the distance less than left table's distance.

```
f <- sum
DT[unique(DT, by=c("group_id", "distance")), on=.(group_id, distance<distance), allow.cartesian=TRUE,
    f(metric), by=.EACHI]
```

output:

```
   group_id distance   V1
1:        1      1.1   NA
2:        1      1.7 1.22
3:        1      2.3 2.15
4:        1      6.3 2.60
5:        1      7.9 2.89
6:        2      2.5   NA
7:        2      2.8 0.78
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("group_id    distance    metric
1         1.1      0.85
1         1.1      0.37
1         1.7      0.93   
1         2.3      0.45 
1         6.3      0.29
1         7.9      0.12
2         2.5      0.78
2         2.8      0.32")
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this would be faster than `data.table` option but here is one way using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(new = purrr::map_dbl(distance, ~f(metric[distance < .])))
```

where `f` is your function. `map_dbl` expects return type of function to be double. If you have different return type for your function you might want to use `map_int`, `map_chr` or likes.

If you want to keep only one entry per `distance` you might remove them using `filter` and `duplicated`

```
df %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(new = purrr::map_dbl(distance, ~f(metric[distance < .]))) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(distance))
```